# How to pass variable to passport strategy via .authenticate?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

This is my current passport authentication mechanism

```
const requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });
```

And my strategy is defined as follows:

```
passport.use('jwt', new Strategy(options, (payload, done) => {
    // my logic
}))
```

Now, I need to change `requireAuth` to function as:

```
function requireAuth(allowProxyLogin) {
    return passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })
}
```

Now, I need to pass this `allowProxyLogin` variable to my strategy. How can I do this, with minimal changes to my strategy?

EDIT:

For the record, I changed the `requireAuth` function to:

```
function requireAuth(allowProxyLogin) {
  return [
    (req, res, next) => {
      req.allowProxyLogin = !!allowProxyLogin;
      return next();
    },
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false, passReqToCallback: true }),
  ];
}
```

To make implementing @Saurabh's answer easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you can do is pass this option 'passReqToCallback' while calling authenticate

```
function requireAuth(allowProxyLogin) {
    return passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false, passReqToCallback: true })
}
```

This will pass request to your verify callback, something like this

```
passport.use('jwt', new Strategy(req, options, (payload, done) => {
    // my logic
}))
```

Now you can add your variable `allowProxyLogin` to request and access it in verify callback.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I edited the question as to how I made my implementation easier

Comment: Happy to help @AyushGupta